# webscraping from cnn function to get text from a article error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i want to get the text from a specific article(not only one) so heres the function therefore:

```
def get_article():
    for url in get_href():
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(4)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        driver.minimize_window()

        text1 = url.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
        print(text1)
```

The error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Informatik\Praktik\Projekte\Python\stiil_working_on\news_automation\try.py", line 116, in <module>
    get_article()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Informatik\Praktik\Projekte\Python\stiil_working_on\news_automation\try.py", line 99, in get_article
    text1 = url.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What i want to do in this function is use the url got from get_href():

```
def get_href():
    all_results = []


    for h3 in soup.select('h3.cnn-search__result-headline > a'):
        title = h3.text
        url_ = h3.get('href')
        abs_url = 'https:'+ url_

        all_results.append(abs_url)


    return all_results
```

and then open it up and webscrape the article text from it but its not wrking and i don't know how to figure it out. Someone know how to do it?

Comment: `url` is only a string with link, not object with HTML. You have to use `soup`  or `driver` to get something from HTML.

Comment: you could add link to previous question, or put rest of code - so people would run it and test problem, and to see web page which you try to scrape. It would help people to create correct solution. At this moment they have to guess if solution will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `url` is a string and a string does not have a method `get()` which you are trying to call, hence the error.
You would need to call `get()` on the parsed HTML which you have in your `soup` variable for it to work. So it would look like this:

```py
text1 = soup.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
```

On another note:
Is there a reason why you use Selenium to web scrape? You could just make a `HTTP GET` request using e.g. [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to download the article which would be significantly faster.

It would then look similar to this.

```py
import sys

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["www.google.com"]

def get_article():
    for url in urls:
        # get page content by HTTP request
        page_response = requests.get(url)
        # check if request was successful
        if page_response.status_code != 200:
            sys.exit(1)

        # parse the website's HTML
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'html.parser')

        # on this you can then call get()
        # NOTE: this will not work for the google page
        text1 = parsed_html.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
        print(text1)
```

Comment: now i get "None" printed in the console my code looks like this: def get_article():
    for url in get_href():
        page_response = requests.get(url)
        if page_response.status_code != 200:
            sys.exit(1)

        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'html.parser')

        text1 = parsed_html.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
        print(text1)

Comment: The request must have been successful as status code 200 was returned otherwise the program would have ended, so there's no error there. You can also use `print(page_response.text)` to verify this. You should see the HTML. 
But `get()` returns `None` if the attribute is not found if I am not mistaken. Because `get()` gets you the value of a `attr` attribute. What you want is actually a `select()` , `select_one()`or a `find()` but you really need to consult the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to figure out which methods you need.

Comment: All those methods offer different ways to locate DOM elements. You are currently using CSS selectors but there are other possibilites which might work better in some circumstances, so as I said the documentation is your best friend for these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 = url.get('div.Paragraph__component > span')
```

would be the below in Selenium

```
text1=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.Paragraph__component > span").text
```

or in beautifulsoup

```
text1 = soup.select_one('div.Paragraph__component > span')
print(text1.text)
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```